# Give the Mathematical Proof of the Square Root finding algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, proof, square-root

Can anyone explain the **mathematical correctness** of the following code to *find the square root of a positive number* in C++ ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float a; cin>>a;
    cout<<"Answer by Math library\n"<<sqrt(a)<<"\n";

    //the following is the code for finding the square root of a positive double

    double g=a;

    while(abs(g*g-a)>1e-8){
        g= (g+(a/g))/2;
    }

    cout<<"Answer by this algorithm\n"<<g<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does seem like a problem suitable for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is primarily a mathematics question, which belongs on [the Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note that this question, as is, probably isn't appropriate for [math.se] given the C++ code. The first step would be to convert that to a more language-agnostic form.

Answer (score 1):

It's an approximate algorithm for computing the square root, called Babylonian method (derived from Newton's method):

[image]

and you can read about it's Convergence in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Convergence).